# Laravel SPA isn't generating CSRF-COOKIE on Ajax request, only when I open the backend route in a new tab

Tags: laravel, single-page-application

Here is the problem:

I make a request to csrf-cookie route, it retuns `204` code, but it just doesn't set the cookie, but if I open the csrf-cookie directly on a new tab and get back to my SPA tab, the cookie is set.

.env:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=192.168.100.110
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=192.168.100.110:5173
```

sanctum.php:

```php
'stateful' => explode(',', env('SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS', sprintf(
    '%s%s',
    'localhost,localhost:3000,127.0.0.1,127.0.0.1:8000,::1',
    Sanctum::currentApplicationUrlWithPort()
))),

'guard' => ['web'], // I've tried "api" too, same issue.
```

cors.php:

```php
'paths' => [
    'api/*',
    'graphql',
    'sanctum/csrf-cookie'
],

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

kernel.php:

```php
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,

    ],

    'api' => [
        \Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class . ':api',
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
    ],
];
```

On my frontend I make a simple request to csrf route:

```js
const onLogin = async () => {
  await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_HTTP_ENDPOINT + 'sanctum/csrf-cookie')
}
```

It returns 204 fine, but no cookie is set, but if I visit this route in a new tab, and refresh my SPA tab, the cookie is now set.

Anyone have any idea what can be happening?

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out my mistake:

In order to share cookies between the frontend and backend I have to set `credentials: "include"` when making the Ajax request to `csrf-cookie` route.

So I just changed my `onLogin` method to:

```js
const onLogin = async () => {
  await fetch(import.meta.env.VITE_HTTP_ENDPOINT + 'sanctum/csrf-cookie', {
    credentials: 'include'
  })
}
```